# Port PHP SHA1 Encrypted Password database to NODE application?

Tags: node.js, passwords, sha

A customer of mine is using Open Cart as an eCommerce platform. They are moving to a custom node-based system and the question has been asked can we port the customers and their logins including sha1 encrypted password which also uses an MD5 salt.

Here is the query that saves the password: 

`$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "customer SET salt = '" . $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)) . "', password = '" . $this->db->escape(sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($password)))) . "' WHERE LOWER(email) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($email)) . "'");`

So if i retrieve the salt for each customer by email address and encrypt the input password with sha1 using the same salt, would I in fact be able to match the input password with the one previously encrypted in PHP and stored in mysql?

Comment: Yes... As long as you use the same logic. Are you looking for a JavaScript solution? You'd be better off finding and porting the PHP code that matches passwords during login rather than saving a password.

Comment: How do you mean "finding and porting the PHP code" that matches passwords. Aside from the inconvenience of having to install and maintain PHP - and all it's dependencies, patches etc -  on the destination server, that's fine for legacy customers but creating new customers .... ? I'd have to have two parallel systems, one for old PHP registration customers and one for new JS registrations ... is that what you're suggesting?